# Python runs two sequential tasks in parallel with the second task only taking the latest/newest return value from the first one

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

Here I have two processes to execute in sequential , say `A` then `B`. The first task `A` outputs a value for the second task `B`, and it takes little time to compute each run. `B` involves some complicated computations, and takes an order of magnitude longer time to finish than `A`.

Meanwhile, Task `B` only fetches the newest return value from `A` when it completes its lengthy computation. The problem is that I don't want to wait for `B` to finish in order for `A` to pick up its next value, in other words, `A` needs to generate its value constantly. What is the correct and expedient way to achieve this functionality in Python?

Simulated Task `A` and `B`:

```py
some_random_value = 0

def a():
    global some_random_value
    while True:
        some_random_value = random.randint(1,100)
        time.sleep(0.01) # fast
        return some_random_value

def b(some_random_value):
    while True:
        time.sleep(2) # slow
        print(some_random_value+1)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why simply using `b(a())` does not work for you? I'm thinking of coroutines, but it isn't really clear what you are trying to achieve.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: @Alexander to clarify, `B` does not need to run on every result returned by `A`. It only listens for the current value of variable `some_random_value`. On the other hand, `A` simply generates newest value for `some_random_value` independent of `B` constantly.

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you?

```
lock = Lock()
some_random_value = 0

def a():
    global some_random_value
    while True:
        with lock.Lock():
            some_random_value = random.randint(1,100)
        time.sleep(0.01) # fast

def b():
    global some_random_value
    while True:
        time.sleep(2) # slow
        with lock.Lock():
            print(some_random_value+1)
```